# Why is $\langle x \rangle =0$ for the ground state hydrogen atom?

Tags: electrons, wavefunction, hydrogen, spherical-harmonics, ground-state

From Griffiths, Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, 2nd ed:

[image]

I found $\langle r \rangle =\frac{3a}{2}$ and $\langle r^2 \rangle =3a^2$. Now I need to find the expectation value of x. However, I don't understand their hint. I understand that $r$ is the radius and $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ is the definition for a sphere in cartesian coordinates. I didn't know how to use the part "exploit the symmetry of the ground state".

**Edit:** I should mention that the answer is $\langle x \rangle =0$ and $\langle x^2 \rangle = \frac{1}{3}\langle r^2 \rangle = a^2$ as given by the solution set. However, I have no clue why.

Comment: The 1s state is spherically symmetric and no angular terms appear, so you can drop them

Comment: The atom is radially symmetrical. $\langle x \rangle =0$ because otherwise the atom would be permanently polarised. $\langle r \rangle =\frac{3a}{2}$  because it's radially symmetrical: the expression is true in *all directions*.

Comment: I had asked the [same](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/287847/expectation-values-of-x-y-z-in-hydrogen) question some days back!

Comment: @CountTo10 question for you: am I correct in interpreting the term ''nth state of the hydrogen atom'' as the nth level wave function (with energy $E_n$)?

Comment: Short answer, or rather the only answer is that it is entirely mathematical....in the sense that $x,y,z$ can vary from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ which gives the $\langle x \rangle$ (the AVERAGE) as zero. It is possible for $\langle x \rangle$ to be zero but $\langle f(x) \rangle$ (namely $r$) to be non zero

Comment: Yes, I would agree with you, on the nth state as being $n $, because $n $ is the first quantum number, the Energy level.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Since you are using Griffiths you might be interested in using the Physics Pages website (sensibly)? :-) http://www.physicspages.com

Answer (score 5):

In spherical coordinates $r$ is the distance from the origin and can only ever be positive.
So the expectation value $\langle r \rangle$ has to be positive.
However in rectangular Cartesian coordinates $x$ can be both positive and negative.
In the case that you are considering with a spherically symmetric wave function you would expect the electron to spend as much time when $x<0$ as when $x>0$ so the expectation value of $x$, $\langle x \rangle =0$.

Since $x^2$ is always positive you would expect its expectation value to be positive.
To find $\langle x^2 \rangle$ you reason that because there is spherical symmetry $\langle x^2 \rangle =\langle y^2 \rangle =\langle z^2 \rangle$ and then use  $\langle r^2 \rangle = \langle x^2 \rangle +\langle y^2 \rangle +\langle z^2 \rangle$ to get your answer.